# Two button one close to other at the bottom of RelativeLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am facing a problem with android layout.
I have a relative layout with a `textview` and an image overlapped and I would like to add two button at the bottom of the view, one close to other and that fill all the width of the view. Here below the `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/RecordAccelDataLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="418dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/bg_thand"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:alpha="0.1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/rec_progress_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_record_accel_data"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.adrenergic.tremorsense.circleGraph
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/progressgraph"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/accelText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/recording"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                />

            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/stats"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:id="@+id/stats"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The layout appears in this way.

[image]

I would like that the two button appear in the same position but `centered` and that they fill equally the view in width.

Hope you will help me.

Comment: Why don't you try your button under another linear layout with same `weight` ? Have you tried it? Hope it may help.

Comment: Yes I have tried but the linear layout appears on the top of the view

Comment: What I am trying to say is answered below by Raghavendra and Ramesh Kumar as well as Sourav Kanta

Comment: @ParideLetizia check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u modify your button layout impl. with the below sample and try.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:weightSum="1">
            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:onClick="goBack"/>

            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/stats"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:id="@+id/stats"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much

Comment: @ParideLetizia Glad! it helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can put buttons in linear layout and align parent bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="283dp"
    android:layout_height="418dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:alpha="0.1"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:src="@mipmap/bg_thand" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec_progress_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_record_accel_data"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.adrenergic.tremorsense.circleGraph
            android:id="@+id/progressgraph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accelText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/recording"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stats"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:text="@string/stats"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

check this it will help.

Answer (score 0):

[android:weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) is what you may be looking for. Enclose the two buttons inside a linear layout and add android:weight =1 for both of them. An example would be :

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            ...
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View 
            android:id="@+id/space"
            ...
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            ...
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `spacer` in in center bottom and align two button to that `spacer` like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.adrenergic.tremorsense.circleGraph
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/progressgraph"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/accelText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                />
             //Aligh Space in center with align to bottom 
               and set relation of two button to this spacer
            <Space
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_above="@+id/back"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/space"/>

            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Back"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/accelText"/>

            <Button
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Status"
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:id="@+id/stats"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/space"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this `layout` changes made with `Button` added inside `Linear Layout` and filled it with `weight` with `android:gravity="bottom"` and `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RecordAccelDataLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="418dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rec_progress_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Progress"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.adrenergic.tremorsense.circleGraph
                android:id="@+id/progressgraph"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accelText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="REcording"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:onClick="goBack"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/stats"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:onClick="goBack"
                    android:text="Stats"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate answer with upvote if somewhere answer making sense to OP.